# How to use read this Array in ReactJS complex

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops

How to use read this Array in ReactJS
->

0: {codes: Array(4), arguments: Array(3), defaultMessage: "not a well-formed email address", objectName: "userVO", field: "email", …}
[Example IMage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh2LZ.png)

Comment: Could you describe your problem more exactly?I'm not sure what you want and the relationship of the example and the code you want?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly if this is what you're asking for but in ES6 you can use the `.map` function to traverse an array and return it's values:

```js
const arr = {codes: Array(4), arguments: Array(3), defaultMessage: "not a well-formed email address", objectName: "userVO", field: "email"}

arr.map(item => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{item.codes}</p>
      <p>{item.defaultMessage}</p>
    </div>
  );
})
```

Comment: I want to create a new var Some thing like this .{ "errors":  { "role":"role cannot be null", "lastName":"Last name should have atleast 1 characters " }  }